# Android studio - adding libraries information

Tags: android-studio

Can someone help me find out how to add this library in android studio

https://github.com/ylyc/circular_progress_bar/blob/master/README.md

i dont know well how to do it , any help is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have to copy CircularProgressBar.java as well as the three resource xml files from the library folder to your project